# is this how to use a posix queue with poll(2)?

Tags: linux, queue, posix, polling

I've read at several places that you can use poll(2) with a posix queue but nowhere on the internet have I found a simple example. So I presumed that it should go like this

```
mq_send(socket->mFd, (const char*)data->getBuffer(), data->getLen(), 0 );
//and then in an other porcess here is my poll
::poll(m_descriptors, ii, msecWaitTime);
```

But this doesnt work, I would expect a POLLIN or POLLRDNORM or maybe POLLRDBAND or whatever to arrive, but it doesnt. And I am quite sure that my descriptor is there in the PollFd array. Am I doing something wrong, or this is correct and the problem is somwhere else in my code? (I'm on OpenSuse, which is a linux, so I guessed this should work).

Comment: You can on some operating systems, e.g. linux. But please show all your code, as the current 2 lines does not tell us anything of importance. Show where you set up the message queue descriptor in the `m_descriptors` , show the types and how `ii` is calculated, etc.

Comment: Hi nos, the code is huge and classified, but if the misake is me setting up m_descriptors and ii incorrectly, then I'll look into it further. I just need to know, whether this example is theoratically correct and should work or this is not how these queues should be polled.

Answer (score 1):

OK, NOS was right. This example is theoratically correct and it really does work on my OpenSuse, it was my mistake to forget filling out the event mask for this fd.